# Excel macro: ignore error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using vba code to vlookup values from an array. Some of the results are "#N/A" and there will be a green triangle on the left top of the cell. I want to remove the green triangle (ignore the error) automatically, but the "#N/A" result should be remained, just remove the green triangle.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It seems as though you can only ignore one cell at a time or it will give you an ***Application-defined or object-defined error***

So, you'll need something like this...

```
Dim Cell As Range, Target As Range

    Set Target = Range("C10:D17")
    For Each Cell In Target
        Cell.Errors(xlEvaluateToError).Ignore = True
    Next
```

Also, see [XlErrorChecks Enumeration (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841186.aspx) for a list of all the errors.

Comment: @Gass, I beg to differ; this method was tested and implemented on Excel 2013 32-bit and worked to satisfaction.  What version are you using?

Comment: microsoft office 365

Answer (score 2):

You need code that looks something like this:

```
Dim r as Range
...
r.Errors.Item(xlEvaluateToError).Ignore = True
```

This will clear the error triangle (xlEvaluateToError equals 1, which is why the previous person had Item(1) in their answer).

The other errors that can occur can be cleared in a similar way, by changing the number of the Item, e.g. I've used a block of code like this to put a value (that might look like a number, but I want to ensure is treated as text) into a cell:

```
With Target_Sheet.Cells(RowNum, ColNum)
    .NumberFormat = "@"     ' Force the cell to be treated as text
    .Value = whatever_value_im_trying_to_set
    .Errors.Item(xlNumberAsText).Ignore = True
End With
```

See the Excel help for Errors.Item Property for the full list of error codes you can check or ignore.

You can also query the value of `.Errors.Item(xlNumberAsText).Value` (or the other error codes) to see if the error is occurring, but you can't set .Value to clear the error.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the green triangle to go away you need to set the Error.Ignore property to true.  For example, if you have a formula such as "=1/0" in cell A1, then in VBA you could do something like this:

```
Dim r as Range
Set r = Range("A1")
r.Errors.Item(1).Ignore = True
```

And the green triangle will go away.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried your method, but returned "Application not-defined" error...@steveo40

Comment: If you copy the code exactly into a new sub and pop the dodgy formula into cell A1 it should work fine.  (Do it in a new workbook.)

Comment: Is that the Item(1) means that there is one cell selected? @steveo40

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP([Your Value], [Your Range], [Your Column], FALSE), NA())
```